# Laravel not calling function inside if statement

Tags: php, laravel, function, if-statement

In laravel 8 I'm trying to pass data to the view blade template. This is my code:

```
Route::get('/admin', function(){
    if (session()->has('username')) {
        return view('admin', ["privatecars"=>[privatecar::class, 'list'], "businesscars"=>[businesscar::class, 'list']]);
    } else {
        session()->flash('blocked', 'true');
        return redirect('');
    }
});
```

I thought that it should call the function inside `[privatecar::class, 'list']` and return the results but it just returns `Array ( [0] => App\Http\Controllers\privatecar [1] => list )` . How should I do to call the function?

PS: I am using laravel8

Comment: you would have to call the method

Comment: How can I call the method? In the view or route file? I am a newbie so pls forgive me for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$param2` in `Route::get($param1, $param2)` is callable, but `param2` in `view($param1, $param2)` only accept `key/value` array. Call them by yourself like this:

```php
Route::get('/admin', function(){
    if (session()->has('username')) {
        $privatecars = (new privatecar())->list();
        $businesscars = (new businesscar())->list();
        return view('admin', ["privatecars" => $privatecars, "businesscars" => $businesscars]);
    } else {
        session()->flash('blocked', 'true');
        return redirect('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if your methods are static yo can try do something like

```
 ["privatecars"=>privatecar::list()]
```

else

```
 ["privatecars"=>(new privatecar())->list()]
```